# FFMPEG Growing Input files

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm having issues with piping the ffmpeg out to the ffmpeg input. I have tried as below

```
ffmpeg -i "y:\3000012936-TXMHD.mxf" -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f mpegts pipe:1 | ffmpeg -re -i pipe:0 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vsync 1 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -c:a aac -c:v libx264 -use_template 1 -use_timeline 1 -init_seg_name  "init-stream$RepresentationID$-$Bandwidth$.mp4" -media_seg_name "chunk-stream$RepresentationID$-$Number%05d$.$ext$" -b:v 1500k -b:a 128k -ac 2 -profile:v main -level:v 3.0  -s 1920x1080 -r 25 -vsync passthrough -increment_tc 1 -adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=v id=1,streams=a" -g 100 -keyint_min 100 -seg_duration 5 -frag_duration 5  -dash_segment_type auto -f dash  "stream.mpd"
```

But I'm getting an error:

> Conversion failed! av_interleaved_write_frame(): Broken pipe Error
> writing trailer of pipe:1: Broken pipe

The input file is MXF, and output is going to be MPEG DASH. The reason to do the piping is because the input file is a growing mxf file. If i do it without piping the ffmpeg just closes before the mxf file is written completely.

Answer (score 1):

Why not let ffmpeg read the file at the same framerate as the source media? If ffmpeg reads at the same speed as the file is written then it will never catch up and close the output.

```
ffmpeg -re -i "y:\3000012936-TXMHD.mxf" . . . . . . . .
```

There needs to be enough data on the source before you start ffmpeg. In case of network drives there could be a delay between writing data and that data being available over the network.